# How can I filter meeting requests and other calendar items in Outlook 2011 with a local client-side rule?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter, microsoft-outlook-2011

A server-side rule has "[Kind] is [Meeting Request]" as an available type of rule filter, but client-side rules do not have the [Kind] filter at all.

Is there an email header that I could use to trigger a client-side rule to mimic that behavior?

Server-side rules with Kind:
[image: server side rule interface screenshot]

Client-side rules without:
[image: client side rule interface screenshot]

Comment: Can you clarify why you want this client side please?

Comment: @DaveRook My Exchange mailbox is very small. I have all of my mail folders as client side folders so that I do not exceed my quota on the Exchange server, and this means my rules have to be client side rules.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the Rules Wizard to create a rule which identifies any item  "which is a meeting invitation or update". (This option is near the very bottom of the list; you might have to scroll down.)

[image: screenshot of Rules Wizard]

Comment: This wizard does not appear to be available in Outlook 2011

Comment: Are you saying there is no Rules Wizard in Outlook 11? Or that the rules wizard doesn't let you filter on that particular condition? (The Rules Wizard in 2010 can be accessed by right-clicking on a mail item, selecting `Rules` -> `Create Rule...` and then clicking the `Advanced Options...` button.)

Comment: There isn't "Advanced Options" after opening the "Create Rule" dialog. In that dialog there is a "Kind"->"Meeting Request" filter available, but that dialog (reached that way) only creates server-side rules. Any way of reaching that dialog from a non-server-side rule list prevents the "Kind" filter from being available.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac Outlook 2011 I use the following client side rule for meeting requests:

```
Specific Header > Content-Class > Contains > calendarmessage
```

Better late than never :)

Comment: I'm staring at the message source of recent meeting-invite. The headers do _not_ have the `Content-Class` header. The message's `Content-Type` is `multipart/alternative` and one of the parts is of the type `text/calendar`...

Comment: I have also found that this only works for some/old requests. Maybe the way requests are sent changed in some platform or version of Outlook?

Answer (score -2):

Go to **Organize > Rules > Create Rule**
Choose *Kind* is *Meeting Request*

[image]

Comment: Did you read the question? "client-side rules do not have the [Kind] filter at all." I am adding screenshots to the question to avoid further answers like this.