# How can I search/filter for calendar invites in OWA?

Tags: calendar, rules, outlook-web-access

I want to make an inbox rule in Outlook on the web to categorize meeting invites/updates/cancellations, but can't find the search or rule syntax.

The [Microsoft rules documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/inbox-rules-in-outlook-web-app-edea3d17-00c9-434b-b9b7-26ee8d9f5622) doesn't have any details about specific filter criteria.

I found [this answer about item type searches](https://superuser.com/a/713419/282374) but it doesn't work in OWA. Searching `messageclass:IPM.Note` or `[Message Class]:IPM.Note` just finds emails with text "IPM".

[This answer using the rules wizard](https://superuser.com/a/638361/282374) uses a specific macOS GUI option that OWA doesn't have.

[This university helppage](https://kb.uwm.edu/uwmhd/page.php?id=46822) uses an email header search `X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop: ePanther@uwm.edu` which led me to a possible solution: creating an email rule with the header search `X-MS-Exchange-Calendar`, which in my inbox I observe all invites having. It seems to work... but it also seems hacky.

Searching for message body text `inviting you to a scheduled Zoom meeting` has a pretty good hit rate as our company uses Zoom exclusively, but your mileage may vary. (This has the added effect of surfacing invitations that have been forwarded as plain emails.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a email rule, with option Message Include > Type > Invitation.

Comment: this is nice to "filter by rule", but what about the search part of the question. did you manage to solve something there?

Comment: @scjorge you could solve this by using the rule to set some folder/category, then search based on that? Not the greatest workaround though...

Comment: I see... Thanx! I found this: https://superuser.com/questions/678617/search-folders-for-arbitrary-email-headers-in-outlook

Comment: For people using outlook app on MAC OS. Open outlook app -> message -> rules

Answer (score 1):

Using search keywords allows you to specify a feature only found in calender invites to quickly return the desired records:

In the mail view, you simply search for organizer:* :) You can of cause add more criteria if you like :)

Comment: In OWA, searching `organizer:*` doesn't work: it returns emails with text "organizers" and doesn't find most calendar invites from my company. Does this only work for you using a different desktop Outlook, instead of Outlook on Web? Or, in your company do people always use the word "organizer" for calendar invites?

Comment: I see... yes, then it's not a generic workaround - it was good for my purpose though. Thanks for pointing it out...